# Parsing HEVC for Motion Information

Tags: hevc

I parsed the HEVC stream by simply identifying sart code (000001 or 00000001), and now I am looking for the motion information in the NAL payload. My goal is to calculate the percentage of the motion information in the stream. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet is to start with the HM reference software (get it here: https://hevc.hhi.fraunhofer.de/svn/svn_HEVCSoftware/trunk/) and add some debug info as the different kinds of data is read from the bitstream.  This is likely much easier than writing bitstream decoder from scratch.

Check out the debug that is built into the software already, for example RExt__DECODER_DEBUG_BIT_STATISTICS or DEBUG_CABAC_BINS.  This may do what you want already, if not it will be pretty close.  I think information about bit usage can be best collected in `source/Lib/TLibDecoder/TDecBinCoderCABAC.cpp` during decode.

If you need to speed this up, you can of course skip the actual decode steps :)

Comment: I did that, but there is no how much motion information (the mode and the motion vectors) in that statistics.

Comment: When I enabled DEBUG_CABAC_BINS flag, I didn't get motion information info since no decoding process taking in place. So, Just enable RExt__DECODER_DEBUG_BIT_STATISTICS flag. I got bit usage in the stream in more detail. Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

At the decoder side, You can find the motion vector information as MVD, so you should using pixel decoding process to get the motion information. it need you to understand the process of the inter prediction at HEVC.

than you!